# React App URL and Backend URL are getting concatenated when fetching data using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my full stack application, I got the **app** folder and a **server** and **client** folder inside.

When going to X URL a `useEffect` is triggered, and it should fetch data from `localhost:4000/pets/cats`, but instead I get an error:

> http://localhost:3000/localhost:4000/pets/cats 404 (Not Found)

For some reason it's trying to look for this URL: `http://localhost:3000/localhost:4000/pets/cats` (that doesn't really exist). How to fix it?

[image: error on the console]

[Here's the get method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Jb0.png)

[image: This is the api]

[The reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8VjP.png)

[The useEffect where I should be getting the info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAD0P.png)

Comment: This can be closed as a typo. You have simply omitted the `//` in `http://`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a proper base URL for [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

An example using full URL:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const url = "http://localhost:4000/pets/cats"; // Full URL
      await axios.get(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Some error: ", err);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

An example using base URL:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const url = "/pets/cats";
      await axios.get(url, {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:4000", // Base URL
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Some error: ", err);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to call api twice so api is not found or 404, try this localhost:4000/pets/cats

Answer (score 0):

axios thinks that your url its not the 'domain' because you forgot the double // in the middle of http and localhost, so axios doest not recognizes it, and takes the default server url that its running on in this case your localhost and then add your url as a complement.

https://stackabuse.com/handling-errors-with-axios/